# Command raised an exception: KeyError: '560849136899850261'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord

I have a problem I can not put **["cash"]** in my json, thank you for helping me

My code :

```
    a = users[str(guildb.id)] = {}
    b = users[str(guildb.id)][str(user.id)]["cash"] = 5000
    c = users[str(guildb.id)][str(user.id)]["bank"] = 10000
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKaKF.png)

Comment: Please copy&paste the traceback text instead of an image - see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

`users` is dictionary. `users[str(guildb.id)]` is dictionary. but `users[str(guildb.id)][str(user.id)]` in your case is not a dictionary.

You need to do it like this :

```
a = users[str(guildb.id)] = {}
b = users[str(guildb.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
c = users[str(guildb.id)][str(user.id)]["cash"] = 5000
d = users[str(guildb.id)][str(user.id)]["bank"] = 10000
```